# SugarORM NullPointerException on save() method

Tags: android

I need a database in my app and I chose SugarORM. But I can't even run a simple example. I have NullPointerException when I use  **`save()`** method.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aleksandr.birukov.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aleksandr.birukov.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="DATABASE"
            android:value="notes.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="QUERY_LOG"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="com.aleksandr.birukov.myapplication" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Note.java

```
package com.aleksandr.birukov.myapplication;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class Note extends SugarRecord {
    String title, note;
    long time;

    public Note() {
    }

    public Note(String title, String note, long time) {
        this.title = title;
        this.note = note;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.aleksandr.birukov.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Note note = new Note("title", "desc", 100);
        note.save();
    }
}
```

I don't understand what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make your class extend SugarRecord< Note >

Comment: I can't. I think in 1.3 version I need extend SugarRecord<Note>, but in version 1.4 there is error when I try to add <Note>

Comment: This page says the latest version is 1.3 (http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html) guess you'll have to read the docs for 1.4 then

Comment: This page says that exist version1.4 https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial-sugar-orm/

Comment: That's a tutorial from 2 years ago. Off-topic, but why do you go for something outdated and not something like Room? If you do want to use Sugar, check here https://github.com/chennaione/sugar which uses 1.5.

Comment: but again, Sugar is an outdated library. Consider using something new.